# Get github copilot recommendations with vscode in a jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I am trying to use github copilot in a jupyter notebook in vscode. It is working great so far, but the short cut to get 10 more recommendation which is "Ctrl + Enter" is already taken in jupyter notebooks to execute the current cell. Is there a recommended solution for this (I assume very common) problem or do I have to creat custom shortcuts?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, there is an easy solution for that.

Simply open your command palette using F1 or Ctrl+Shift+P. Than enter "Open Github Copilot" and the suggestion tab will open:
[image]

The Output will look as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the default keyboard shortcut.

I checked and Ctrl+Alt+Enter doesn't seem to do anything yet inside a notebook, so let's use that one.

Ctrl+P > Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)
Add the following to the list:

```
    { "key": "ctrl+alt+enter",            "command": "github.copilot.generate",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && github.copilot.activated && !inInteractiveInput && !interactiveEditorFocused" },
```